# Terraform cannot read from remote state

Tags: amazon-s3, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

#### Terraform version

v0.12.1

#### AWS provider version

v2.16.0

I've Terraform workspace configured, as for now my workspace is pointing to `dev` where I've a tfstate file for my VPCs and Subnets and a different one for my security groups, however when I'm trying to refer `vpc_id` from my vpc remote tfstate into my security group then I get below error message

`No stored state was found for the given workspace in the given backend.`

My s3 bucket looks like below

```
nonprod-us-east-1
  |-- env
         |-- dev
                |-- vpc_subnet/tfstate
                |-- security_group/tfstate
```

#### Terraform Configuration Files

Security-Group tf config

```
terraform {
    backend "s3"{
        # Configuration will be injected by environment variables.
    }
}

provider "aws" {
  region = "${var.region}"
}


data "terraform_remote_state" "vpc_subnet" {
  backend = "s3"

  config = {
    bucket  = "nonprod-us-east-1"
    key     = "vpc_subnet/tfstate"
    region  = "us-east-1"
  }
}

 vpc_id = "${data.terraform_remote_state.vpc_subnet.outputs.vpc_id}"
```

And I've verified that my `vpc_subnet/tfstate`  oputputs has `vpc_id`

#### Outputs from VPC subnet tf state

```
outputs": {
    "private_subnet_cidr_blocks": {
      "value": [
        "10.0.3.0/24",
        "10.0.4.0/24",
        "10.0.5.0/24"
      ],
      "type": [
        "tuple",
        [
          "string",
          "string",
          "string"
        ]
      ]
    },
    "private_subnet_ids": {
      "value": [
        "subnet-042a16dd291e90add",
        "subnet-02e8322d996968a3f",
        "subnet-078f525c24015b364"
      ],
      "type": [
        "tuple",
        [
          "string",
          "string",
          "string"
        ]
      ]
    },
    "public_subnet_cidr_blocks": {
      "value": [
        "10.0.0.0/24",
        "10.0.1.0/24",
        "10.0.2.0/24"
      ],
      "type": [
        "tuple",
        [
          "string",
          "string",
          "string"
        ]
      ]
    },
    "public_subnet_ids": {
      "value": [
        "subnet-0ba92a28f6e8ddd95",
        "subnet-08efcb80bed22f4e2",
        "subnet-0b641797bfe207a0b"
      ],
      "type": [
        "tuple",
        [
          "string",
          "string",
          "string"
        ]
      ]
    },
    "vpc_id": {
      "value": "vpc-0bb7595ff05fed581",
      "type": "string"
    }
  }
```

#### Expected Behavior

It should be able to read `vpc_id` from remote tf state location.

#### Actual Behavior

Failing to read output from remote tf state

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally sorted it out, it comes out to be an issue with bucket key, since I'm using Terraform workspace so the tfstate files are created under folder `env:/dev/vpc_subnet/tfstate`, after correcting bucket key, it's able to resolve the tfstate files.